# Understanding the 2007 PDG-Review on Constants

Tags: particle-physics, data

I have a question concerning the following table: 
http://pdg.lbl.gov/2007/reviews/consrpp.pdf

Let's take the Weinberg-mixing angle as an example, whose sine-squared is stated as $$\sin^2 \theta_W = 0.231 22(15).$$ Now, I have difficulties in understanding their uncertainty (last column). What does $1 \ \text{ppb}$ mean? Is $1 \ \text{ppb} = 0.000 000 000 1 = 10^{-10}$? If so, then I could write that $$\sin^2\theta_W = 0.23122 \pm 6 \cdot 10^{-5},$$ couldn't I?

Comment: Pls use current review,  http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2018-rev-phys-constants.pdf .

Comment: Sure, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table caption says

> The figures in parentheses after the values give the 1-standard-deviation uncertainties
>   in the last digits; the corresponding fractional uncertainties in parts per $10^9$ (ppb) are given in the last column.

So $6.5\times 10^{5} \,\text{ppb} = 6.5\times10^{-4}$ is the fractional uncertainty. We can confirm from the given 1-standard deviation uncertainty that
\begin{align}
\frac{0.00015}{0.23122} = 0.00065
\end{align}

You could write instead
\begin{align}
\sin^2\theta_{W} = 0.23122 \pm 0.00015.
\end{align}